# UISearchbar results showing inconsistently in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, nsthread

I am using a real-time search against an external API (XML) based on what the user is entering in the search bar..

I am using a case-insensitive search. The thing was working fine, until I moved the code or rather added a thread.  Suddenly the results that I get are a bit consistent. They are not incorrect, but they are sometimes lesser in number.

e.g. if a user enters "a", it will show around 7 results, say AAR, Aaron, Staar,Mtaar ...
Then if enters "aa" , it will show 1 result (AAR), then if he enters "aar", it will show 3 results AAR, Star, Mtaar
Again if backspace is pressed and if the current term in the search bar is aa, it will now show 3 results...

Another example, if I type "goog", it displays nothing in the table cell results (even though i see that it has parsed Google), while if i add an "l", i.e. if the term is now "googl", it now shows Google in the cell below.
I am updating my table view immediately after the parsing is complete.

So basically after I added thread, the search results have got a bit inconsistent. I am not sure why.

Note that in all cases the results shown are all correct, but just the no. of them is varying.

Could someone please help me with the issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you provide some sample code how you access your filtered table content array? You can NSLog() the result you get from the API and compare with the ones are displayed in your tableView.